# Calling Invoke() with async delegate in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I have a WinForms (.NET 4.7.2) app reading data from serial barcode scanner and returning it back to GUI.

My async SerialDataReceivedEventHandler is:

```
private async void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   if (_serialPort != null && _serialPort.IsOpen)
   {
       string data = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
       if (this.InvokeRequired)
       {
          this.Invoke(new Func<Task>(async () => await HandleDataFromScannerAsync(data)));
       }             
   }
}

private async Task HandleDataFromScannerAsync(string text) {
...do async stuff...
}
```

I have to use `Invoke()` in `Port_DataReceived()`, because the data from serial scanner are read in different thread.

This code is working, but...is it properly asynchronnous? I'm aware of calling `async void` methods.

I read Stephen Cleary's article about [Synchronous and Asynchronous Delegate Types](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html), and that's why I'm using `new Func<Task>(async () => await HandleDataFromScannerAsync(data))`.

So when calling `Invoke()`, shouldn't it be awaited in some way? Like `await this.Invoke(...)` or somehow.  I tried `BeginInvoke()` instead of `Invoke()`. I understand the difference, but I'm not sure which is the right way. Both ways seem to work.

So my question is - how to properly call `Invoke()` with asynchronous delegate?

Comment: Have you tried `await this.Invoke`? `Control.Invoke(Func<T>)` returns `T`, which in your case is `Task` and can be awaited.

Comment: @johnathan-barclay I did and the compiler says `'object' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found `. It seams that `Control.Invoke(Func<T>)` returns `object` form some reason.

Comment: OK, it looks like [the generic version was introduced in Windows Desktop 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-control-invoke-1(system-func((-0)))), so if your targeting .Net Framework, you will be calling `this.Invoke(Delegate)` which returns `object`, so you will need to cast.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay It seems to be working :-) Thank you for this help. But here comes another issue - I need to make second barcode scan while running `HandleDataFromScannerAsync()`. And because `this.Invoke(HandleDataFromScannerAsync)` is awaited now, so it doesn't return/finish into `Port_DataReceived()` before the `HandleDataFromScannerAsync()` is finished. How to solve this problem? I still can use `BeginInvoke` (not awaited) and it seems to be working either, but I'm not sure it's the proper way.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
    public async Task<string> ExecuteScript(string script)
    {
        Func<Task<string>> func = async () =>
        {
            await webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(script)
        };
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            var task = (Task<string>)Invoke(func);
            return await task;
        }
        else
        {
            return await func();
        }
    }
```